# python: print 5 minute interval for a given date

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have input list which consists of event_dates

```
event_date
-----------
2020-05-21 01:00:45.783000
2020-05-22 01:04:25.549000
2020-05-22 01:07:27.543000
2020-05-22 01:09:57.472000
2020-05-22 01:10:57.472000
2020-05-22 01:13:00.627000
2020-05-22 01:15:00.645000
2020-05-22 01:18:23.830000
2020-05-22 01:20:24.423000
2020-05-22 01:22:39.490000
```

i need `five_minute_intervals` value for each `event_date`

```
if minutes between
[00-04] ==> 05
[05-09] ==> 10
[10-14] ==> 15
[15-19] ==> 20
[20-24] ==> 25
      :
      :
```

i am looking for output like below

```
event_date                       minute       five_minute_intervals
--------------------------------------------------------------
2020-05-21 01:00:45.783000          00           05
2020-05-22 01:04:25.549000          04           05
2020-05-22 01:07:27.543000          07           10
2020-05-22 01:09:57.472000          09           10
2020-05-22 01:10:57.472000          10           15
2020-05-22 01:13:00.627000          13           15
2020-05-22 01:15:00.645000          15           20
2020-05-22 01:18:23.830000          18           20
2020-05-22 01:20:24.423000          20           25
2020-05-22 01:22:39.490000          22           25
```

**Can anyone suggest a solution in python?**

Answer (score 0):

def get_result(date):
    var = 1
    if (int(date.minute / 5)) == (date.minute / 5):
         var = 0
    print(date, date.minute, ((int(date.minute / 5) + var) * 5))